# prevent default scope from being applied to acts_as_list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-list

I use [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) to generate slot numbers of books:

`acts_as_list :scope => :book_id, :column => :slot`

and have a default scope that prevents deleted (soft delete) books from getting in to result sets:

`default_scope where(:is_active => true)`

I want to prevent the default scope from getting applied to the acts_as_list declaration, because if someone deletes the last book, and creates a new one, they get the same slot number (because when it fetches the last slot number, the default scope gets applied and it doesn't get the deleted entry). I am aware of `unscoped`, but how do I use it with acts_as_list?

I am using Rails 3.0.11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wherever you use `acts_as_list`

just do this instead,

```
unscoped.acts_as_list
```

Comment: You define it in the model. It is not a named scope. You can look at the documentation here: https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list

Comment: you can prefix `acts_as_list` with `unscoped` when defining it - `acts_as_list` is just a method that gets called on the class, and so is `unscoped`, so there's nothing wrong with chaining them: `unscoped.acts_as_list`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It seems there was some bug in version 0.1.4, due to which it didn't work. It seems to have been fixed in 0.1.8: https://github.com/rails/acts_as_list/pull/11

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the older version (0.1.4) of the gem had some bug and `unscoped.acts_as_list` didn't prevent the default scope from getting applied. Updating the gem to the latest version (0.1.8) fixed it. By default, it doesn't apply the default scope, so we don't need to write `unscoped.acts_as_list`

More details can be found here:

https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/pull/13